# MVVMCross binaries: which ones to include when working on both mac and win8

Tags: mono, mvvmcross

My setup for a mvvmcross project supporting iOS, Android and Win8 is to have two separate .sln files, one including the core, iOS and Android projects (for development in xamarin studio on mac) and one including core and winphone projects (for development in vs2012 on win8). However, I don't know which mvvmcross binaries (https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Binaries) I should reference from my different .csproj files in this situation as there are two versions. Question is: what exactly is the difference between the two builds (XS-iOS-Mac and VS2012) and which binaries should I include for a working cross-platform setup? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two sets of binaries is that PCLs built on the Mac using the current Xamarin Stable releases are not true portable class libaries - see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/almost-portable-binaries.html

This situation is currently 'in flux' - the latest alpha release from Xamarin is starting to produce real PCL binaries - see http://deapsquatter.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/xamarin-pcl-support-hoorah.html

Until this transition is complete, if you want to work off of the pre-built binaries, then one easy method is to:

- link to binaries in a folder - e.g. in : `/lib/Mvx/`
- on the PC, fill this folder from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Binaries/tree/master/VS2012/bin/Release
- on the Mac, fill this folder from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Binaries/tree/master/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release

Alternatively, the nuget packages attempt to do this for you - and seem to work with one exception (a problem with using `MvxCommand` which is easily worked around using your own `MyCommand` in your Core project)

Comment: I installed the nuget add-in for xamarin studio from https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin on my mac, but when I try to install package mvvmcross into my core project it throws me: "Could not install package 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.9'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-Profile104', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author." The latter is you ;-) Any thoughts on that? Thanks for all you effort!

Comment: Please try to avoid starting conversations in comments - they're too hard to read. Better to start a new question when you have a new question. Alternatively, if you want a conversation then try Xamarin forums - or just search around for other people who are trying to use nuget on Mac (I'm not - so I can't help you) - others can - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653208/mvvmcross-nuget-nuspec-android-and-ios-version and https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin/issues/13 - over and out from me on this thread.