# Missing .NETPortable folder?

Tags: mono, xamarin

I switched to the alpha channel on Xamarin Studio and upgraded to 4.1.11 (Build 10). However, PCL is not working and when I look at the .NETPortable folder, it is not present. Is there something else I am missing to install this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin is still working on PCL support. Though its there but its shaky. You can get PCL to work for you by copying .NETPortable folder from your PC to Mac as intructed here.

[Getting PCL, Mvvmcross, Nuget and Xamarin Studio to play "nice" on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653208/getting-pcl-mvvmcross-nuget-and-xamarin-studio-to-play-nice-on-mac)

http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Portable-Class-Library-td4659991.html

Comment: Be sure to read *all* the comments, because switching to and from alpha gave me lots of troubles, lost two days to get it all working again (most pitfalls are mentioned in the comments).

Comment: Yeah correct. Its better if you have an extra PC to tinker around with.