# NullReference exception during binding with MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

I have an MonoTouch project using MvvmCross.  I am at the point where I could get my core project code compiling (with quite a bit of effort), and now I am creating the views for iOS.  Running the latest stable releases of Xamarin tools, as well as MvvmCross. Also, I am running against iOS7 SDK with XCode 5 installed.

To start off I created a very basic view with a text field binding to my main view model.  The relevant code in the view is as follows:

```
[Register("MainView")]
public partial class MainView : MvxViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        View = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.White };

        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var uiTextField = new UITextField(new RectangleF(0, 100, 320, 100));
        Add(uiTextField);

        this.CreateBinding(uiTextField).To<MainViewModel>(vm => vm.IsDebug).Apply();

    }
}
```

The binding however throws a NullReference exception with the following stack trace:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBaseFluentBindingDescription`1[MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField].SourcePropertyPath[MainViewModel] (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1 sourceProperty) [0x00000] in :0
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxFluentBindingDescription`1[MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField].To[MainViewModel] (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1 sourceProperty) [0x00000] in :0
  at ProjectX.Views.MainView.ViewDidLoad () [0x000a4] in /Users/jerriepelser/Development/1degree Software/ProjectX/Source/ProjectX.MonoTouch/Views/MainView.cs:26
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible () [0x00010] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIWindow.g.cs:129
  at ProjectX.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0003c] in /Users/jerriepelser/Development/1degree Software/ProjectX/Source/ProjectX.MonoTouch/AppDelegate.cs:27
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at ProjectX.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/jerriepelser/Development/1degree Software/ProjectX/Source/ProjectX.MonoTouch/Main.cs:16

If I set a breakpoint before the binding I can confirm that the ViewModel is set correctly on the base MvxViewController class, so it is not a problem with the ViewModel not being set.

I also tried the following way of doing the data binding:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MainView, MainViewModel> ();
set.Bind (uiTextField).To (vm => vm.IsDebug);
set.Apply ();
```

Still get a NullReference exception, but with the following stack trace:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
        at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBaseFluentBindingDescription`1[MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField].SourcePropertyPath[MainViewModel] (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1 sourceProperty) [0x00000] in :0
            at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxFluentBindingDescription`2[MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField,OneLove.Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel].To (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1 sourceProperty) [0x00000] in :0
            at OneLove.Views.MainView.ViewDidLoad () [0x000a6] in /Users/jerriepelser/Development/1degree Software/OneLove/Source/OneLove.MonoTouch/Views/MainView.cs:29
            at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr)
            at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible () [0x00010] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIWindow.g.cs:129
            at OneLove.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0003c] in /Users/jerriepelser/Development/1degree Software/OneLove/Source/OneLove.MonoTouch/AppDelegate.cs:27
            at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
            at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
            at OneLove.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/jerriepelser/Development/1degree Software/OneLove/Source/OneLove.MonoTouch/Main.cs:16

Looking at the MvvmCross debug output gives me no hint as to what is wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: No idea. The error suggests that perhaps you are missing one of the parsers - but I can't think of any way you'd miss those in a normal 'first app' set. Maybe you've got a mix-and-match set of assemblies somehow or maybe there is a Xamarin setup issue? Does a simple test project like https://github.com/slodge/Enabling work for you? If yes, then see if you can spot the difference. If no, then please update question with complete trace (or link to a gist with complete trace)

Comment: I could not get MvvmCross working in Xamarin Studio with NuGet, so I downloaded the latest binaries and referenced that.  I do not know whether it is an assembly mixup as I am referencing everything from the same "Touch" folder, other than the few which I am referencing from the "Portable" folder.  Will go through it again though as you suggested, as I did everything by hand and a screwup on my side is possible.

Comment: Started a new project and got the Nuget packages working as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653208/getting-pcl-mvvmcross-nuget-and-xamarin-studio-to-play-nice-on-mac.  It is working fine like that, so I will strip my project back to the bones tomorrow and try and figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I solved it. I think that this answer may not apply to every situation, but I my case it sorted the problem out.

I was doing some platform specific IOC registration in the InitializeLastChance method on the Setup class, but did not make a call to base.InitializeLastChance().  This does not cause a problem on either WinRT or Windows Phone 8, but on MonoTouch it results in the error I experienced.  So I did a simple call to the base class method, and all is resolved :)

```
protected override void InitializeLastChance()
{
    base.InitializeLastChance ();

    // Do some platform specific registration here...
}
```

If someone else out there experiences something similar, this may be a possible cause of the error.

Edit:
Just a quick afterthought... Looking at the source code for the base MvxTouchSetup class, this actually makes perfect sense now:

```
protected override void InitializeLastChance()
{
    InitialiseBindingBuilder();
    base.InitializeLastChance();
}
```

See the call to InitialiseBindingBuilder()...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using Views generated from code.

The Viewmodel is set, but the bindingcontext is not completely set. Here is some example code from my project to get you up and running for other issues you will encounter:

```
public abstract class IndexBaseFragment<T> : MvxFragment where T : class, IMvxViewModel {
        public static int WRAP = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent;
        public static int FILL = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent;

        public LinearLayout NewVerticalLinearLayout(Orientation orientation, Boolean fillparent) {
            var ll = new LinearLayout (Activity) { Orientation = orientation };
            ll.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, fillparent ? FILL : WRAP);
            return ll;
        }

        public new T ViewModel { get { return base.ViewModel as T; } set { base.ViewModel = value; } } 

        // These are the available controls
        protected ListView list {get; set;}
        protected MvxListView ListAsMvxListView {get { return (MvxListView) list; }}
        protected TextView emptytext { get; set; }
        protected TextView title { get; set; }
        protected Button twobuttonklein { get; set; }
        protected Button twobuttongroot { get; set; }
        protected EditText zoekvak {get; set;}



        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var layout = NewVerticalLinearLayout (Orientation.Vertical, true);


            if (ViewModel == null)
                ViewModel = Mvx.IocConstruct<T> ();
            BindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext (Activity, new MvxSimpleLayoutInflater(inflater), ViewModel);
            using (new MvxBindingContextStackRegistration<IMvxAndroidBindingContext>(((IMvxAndroidBindingContext) this.BindingContext)))
            {
                //var layout = NewVerticalLinearLayout (Orientation.Vertical, true);
                layout.SetBackgroundColor (Color.ParseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                var titlelayer = NewVerticalLinearLayout (Orientation.Horizontal, false);
                titlelayer.LayoutParameters.Height = 40;
                title = new TextView (Activity) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, FILL) };
                title.SetTextColor (Color.ParseColor ("#212121"));
                title.SetPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
                title.TextSize = 18;
                var titlebutton = new Button (Activity) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (WRAP, FILL) };
                titlelayer.AddView (title);
                titlelayer.AddView (titlebutton);
                layout.AddView (titlelayer);

                var twobuttonlayer = NewVerticalLinearLayout (Orientation.Horizontal, false);
                twobuttonlayer.LayoutParameters.Height = 40;
                twobuttonklein = new Button (Activity) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, WRAP) };
                twobuttonklein.Text = "Klein";
                twobuttonklein.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.kleingrootbutton);
                twobuttongroot = new Button(Activity){ LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, WRAP) };
                twobuttongroot.Text = "Middel/groot";
                twobuttongroot.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.kleingrootbutton);
                twobuttonlayer.AddView (twobuttonklein);
                twobuttonlayer.AddView (twobuttongroot);
                layout.AddView (twobuttonlayer);

                zoekvak = new EditText (Activity) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, WRAP) };
                zoekvak.Hint = "Zoek in inhoudsopgave";
                layout.AddView (zoekvak);

                emptytext = new TextView (Activity) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, FILL),
                    Text = "Er zijn geen resultaten." };
                layout.AddView (emptytext);

                CreateList();

                layout.AddView (list);


            }




            //var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.IndexTocView, null);
            Console.WriteLine ("LAYOUT RETURNED");

            return layout;
        }

        protected abstract void BindView();

        protected MvxAdapter listadapter { get; set; }


        protected virtual void CreateList () {
            // let op, deze code is nog voor de speciale situatie, en dat moet juist andersom.
            listadapter = new MvxAdapter(this.Activity, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);

            list = new MvxListView(Activity, null, listadapter) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(FILL, FILL) };
            list.SetMinimumHeight(50);

        }

        public override void OnResume ()
        {
            base.OnResume ();
            BindView ();
        }




    }
```

Comment: Oops sorry, this is Android code. I will leave this for other who run into these problems.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a better answer:

- Step 1: you are mixing up things: if you create your own view, override LoadView instead of ViewDidLoad. And make sure there is no associated Xib.
- Step 2: in loadview, call ViewDidLoad because of a MvvmCross shortcoming (it will bind the ViewModel after ViewDidLoad, but ViewDidLoad is only called after a Xib).

I think MvvmCross holds a reference to the original View, instead of the (late created) View you define in ViewDidLoad.

Using MvvmCross without Xibs work fine (I never create any Xib anymore), and I really recommend XibFree (take my fork to have extended functionality).

Comment: '`ViewDidLoad` is only called after a Xib' doesn't sound correct to me. It's called the first time the View is referenced regardless of whether it is Xib loaded or not - there are hundreds of Mvx examples of this now - e.g. all of these in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs.

Comment: `I think MvvmCross holds a reference to the original View` - not that I'm aware of - there *should be* no UIView references bound to until you start creating/applying bindings. If you find there is, please do log an issue.

Comment: @Stuart, I'll test them later if I can build iOS again :( Since I switched to Xibless building two years ago, I have always been weary of this problem: ViewDidLoad is not always called when it should. But I think in this case I added the ViewDiDLoads to prepare the databinding in LoadView without having to expose all items as classwide properties/fields. But I'll check it out later. All done in the name of 'App is King' :)

Comment: Sorted the issue and posted the answer.  Thanks in any case for the ideas guys.